# Which are the natural morphisms between binary relations?

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory

Which properties should morphisms $\alpha$ between binary relations have?

$
(1) \qquad R \overset \alpha \longrightarrow R\,', \;R\subseteq X\times Y, \;R\,'\subseteq X'\times Y' 
$

Can those properties be expressed as relations $M_1$, $M_2$ below?

$
(2) \qquad M_1\subseteq X\times X', \;M_2\subseteq Y\times Y'
$

If so, is the diagram commutative then?
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X @>M_1>> X'\\
@VRV V @VV R\,'V\\
Y @>>M_2> Y'
\end{CD}
Except for the commutative condition there is an other natural condition considering $R$ and $R\,'$ as (bipartite) graphs:

$
(3) \qquad (x,x')\in M_1\wedge(y,y')\in M_2\Rightarrow [(x,y)\in R\Rightarrow (x',y')\in R\,']
$

There is a counter-example below showing that the condition on the diagram being commutative, not in general imply $(3)$, if $M_1$ and $M_2$ not are functions.

What about if $M_1$ and $M_2$ are functions?

---

**Counter-example**? $X=X'=Y=Y'=\mathbb{N}$ and $R=R\,'=M_1=M_2\wedge [(x,y)\in R \Leftrightarrow x<y]$

Answer (score 0):

I think the most natural definition might just be

> A morphism of relations $\alpha\colon R\to R'$ is a pair $(M_1,M_2)$ of relations $M_1\colon X\to X'$ and $M_2\colon Y\to Y'$ such that $R'\circ M_1=M_2\circ R$.

This definition at least makes the class of relations and morphisms into a category, and your diagram commutes by definition. You could of course restrict the hom sets to just functions making the diagram commute. I'm not sure how interesting these two categories are though.

Comment: Do you think that the morphism should have the property that $(x,y)\in R \wedge ((x,y),(x',y'))\in\alpha \Rightarrow (x',y')\in R'$? If so, can you prove that for your suggestion?

Comment: $M_1$ is a subset of $X\times X'$, not $X\times Y$ (similarly for $M_2$). Did you mean something else?

Comment: No, but I just call the morphism $\alpha$. I mean $((x,y),(x',y'))\in\alpha\Leftrightarrow (x,x')\in M_1 \wedge (y,y')\in M_2$. Have I made a mistake?

Comment: Ah I see. Suppose for $y\in Y$, we have $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,y')\in M_2$. Then $(x,y')\in M_2\circ R$ and so $(x,y')\in R'\circ M_1$. It follows that there must exist some $x'\in X'$ such that $(x,x')\in M_1$ and $(x',y')\in R'$. Is this the sort of thing you wanted?

Comment: What I would like is: if $(x,x')\in M_1 \wedge (y,y')\in M_2$, then $(x,y)\in R \Rightarrow (x',y')\in R'$. And I wonder if that can be proved from the commuting construction?

Comment: Suppose $(x',y')\notin R'$, then if $(x,x')\in M_1$, it means that $(x,y')\notin R'\circ M_1$ which means that $(x,y')\notin M_2\circ R$. But if $(y,y')\in M_2$ then if $(x,y)\in R$ we must have $(x,y')\in M_2\circ R$, which is a contradiction. It follows that if $(x,x')\in M_1$ and $(y,y')\in M_2$, then if $(x,y)\in R$ we must also have $(x',y')\in R'$. (So many connectives. Don't know if this is right. Please check.)

Comment: To be honest, just draw up the truth table, the above is a mess.

Comment: there is a counter-example for $M_1,M_2$ not being functions. I will edit the question.

Comment: No, it was no counter-example but I will work on it.